# Как сделать LINQ LEFT JOIN в данном случае?

Tags: c#, linq

Имеются вот такие классы:

```
   class Project
    {
        public int project_id { get; set; }
        public List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    }
    class Task
    {
        public int task_id { get; set; }
        public string singleThreaded { get; set; }
    }
```

В программе есть 2 `List<Project>`, которые нужно соединить левым соединением.
По сути в итоге должно получится что-то типа следующего:
Там где project_id нету в правом List'e там проставляется NULL, там где project_id присутствует справа, но часть task_id отсутствует напротив этих Task_id должен поставиться так же null.
Как соединить про project_id я знаю, а как дальше быть с соединением по task_id я не понимаю.

Comment: Покажите примерные данные, и какой вы хотите результат.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возможно, вам хочется что-то вроде этого:

```
from mainproject in l1
join subproject in l2 on mainproject.project_id equals subproject.project_id into pj
from adjoinedproject in pj.DefaultIfEmpty()
select (adjoinedproject == null) ? mainproject : new Project()
{
    project_id = mainproject.project_id,
    taskList =
       (from t in mainproject.taskList
        join subp in adjoinedproject.taskList on t.task_id equals subp.task_id into tj
        from adjoinedtask in tj.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select adjoinedtask ?? new Task() { task_id = t.task_id, name = null }).ToList()
};
```

Вот [официальный пример на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

можете попробовать так

```
l1 = l1
     .Join(
          l2,
          t => t.project_id,
          i => i.project_id,
          (t, i) => new { t, i })
     .Select(
          s => s.i == null ? s.t : new Project()
          {
               project_id = s.t.project_id,
               taskList = s.t.taskList
                    .Join(
                         s.i.taskList,
                         z = z.task_id,
                         y = y.task_id,
                         (z, y) => new { z, y })
                    .Select(
                         c => c.y == null ? c.z.task_id : new Task()
                         {
                              task_id = c.y.task_id,
                              name = null
                         }
                    .ToList()
          }).ToList();
```

Comment: но я не тестил, могут быть ошибки